# How to break out of a loop in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

I want to write a Bash script to process text, which might require a while loop.

For example, a while loop in C:

```c
int done = 0;
while(1) {
  ...
  if(done) break;
}
```

I want to write a Bash script equivalent to that. But what I usually used and as all the classic examples I read have showed, is this:

```
while read something;
do
...
done
```

It offers no help about how to do `while(1){}` and `break;`, which is well defined and widely used in C, and I do not have to read data for stdin.

Could anyone help me with a Bash equivalent of the above C code?

Answer (score 315, accepted):

It's not that different in `bash`.

```
workdone=0
while : ; do
  ...
  if [ "$workdone" -ne 0 ]; then
      break
  fi
done
```

`:` is the no-op command; its exit status is always 0, so the loop runs until `workdone` is given a non-zero value.

---

There are many ways you could set and test the value of `workdone` in order to exit the loop; the one I show above should work in any POSIX-compatible shell.

Comment: also note: depending on how complex the work that is done, you may also use `&& break` or `|| break` depending on the expected return value

Answer (score 86):

```
while true ; do
    ...
    if [ something ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```