# Auto remove container with docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`docker-compose run` has a flag `--rm` that auto removes the container after run. I am wondering if theres an equivalent config with docker-compose.yml for a specific service, as one of which services i got in yml is a one off build process which should just output the compile file and disappear itself.

Comment: **still not possible in 2018-11** :(  don't waste time searching like me (at least not in the next few months ;))

Comment: I'm using ````docker-compose up -d && docker-compose rm -f```` for a similar scenario.

Comment: @MauriceMüller Don't you know if there're any updates?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I haven't found any option to help you define this behavior in the `docker-compose.yml` file and I think the explanation is the that it will break how some of the `docker-compose ...` commands are supposed to work.

More on this `up`/`down` , `start`/`stop` thing:

> `docker-compose up` builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.

Since your `images` are built and the `containers` of your service have started, you can then use `docker-compose stop` and `docker-compose start` to start/stop your service. This is different from `docker-compose down` which:

> Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by `up`.

**Problem with what you are trying to do:**

If you `docker-compose up` and one of your containers finishes its task and gets (auto)removed, then you can't `docker-compose stop` and `docker-compose start` again. The removed container will not be there to `start` it again.

---

You might want to take a look at:

- [docker-compose: option to automaticaly remove container after run in docker-compose.yml](https://serverfault.com/questions/750175/docker-compose-option-to-automaticaly-remove-container-after-run-in-docker-comp)
- [What is the difference between docker-compose up and docker-compose start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715499/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-compose-up-and-docker-compose-start)

Comment: Ya thats confirmed my research accepted as answer. It be nice if theres an option since one of the container just there to do one off webpack production build. Guess need to write bash for it

Comment: Check if `docker-compose rm` fits your needs... [https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/rm/](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/rm/)

Answer (score 67):

Simply run `docker-compose up && docker-compose rm -fsv`

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/rm

> Removes stopped service containers

> ```
> --force , -f      Don't ask to confirm removal
> --stop , -s       Stop the containers, if required, before removing
> --volumes , -v    Remove any anonymous volumes attached to containers
> ```

---

alternatively you can do in bash:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eux
cleanup() {
    docker compose rm -fsv
}
trap cleanup EXIT
docker compose up
```

Comment: This helps but I still wish `docker-compose up` had a `--rm` flag like `docker run` has.

Comment: @Iwazaru `docker-compose up -V`?

Comment: With this approacth you can't remove a container if you stop the it using `SIGTERM` (CTRL+C)

Comment: I don't get it, when is "docker-compose up" supposed to exit with 0 code to run the "rm" part? I'll probably stick to NPM "concurrently" coupled with 2 Docker commands for my simple use case (running a MongoDB and a RedisDb during app development)

Comment: This only removes the container if the process ends successfully.

Comment: If you want to use SIGTERM, using `docker-compose up --build || docker-compose rm -fsv` works fine

Answer (score 21):

It's been quite some time since this question was posted, but I thought it would be informative to share something that worked for my case, in 2022 :)
But keep in mind that this solution still does not remove old containers, as the original author intended to achieve.

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate -V
```

In my case, I have a small Redis cluster where I want the data to be completely erased after I stop the servers.
Only using `--force-recreate` didn't do the trick, because the anonymous volume is still reused. That's where `-V` comes in.

Answer (score 8):

My solution to this was to create a little bash script that automatically removes containers afterwards.

If you're on macOS, you can put this script in `usr/local/bin`. Assuming it's named `dco`, you can then run `chmod +x usr/local/bin/dco` to make it executable. On Windows, I have no idea how to get this working, but on Linux it should be similar.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

# check for -d, --detached
DETACHED=false
for (( i=1; i <= "$#"; i++ )); do
  ARG="${!i}"
  case "$ARG" in
    -d|--detach)
      DETACHED=true
      break
      ;;
  esac
done

if [[ $1 == "run" ]] && [[ $DETACHED == false ]]; then
    docker-compose run --rm "${@:2}"
elif [[ $1 == "up" ]] && [[ $DETACHED == false ]]; then
    docker-compose up "${@:2}"; docker-compose down
else
    docker-compose "${@:1}"
fi
```

**Edit:** Updated the script so that detached mode will work normally, added `break` to the loop suggested by artu-hnrq

Comment: Nice solution! Yet your `for` stills looping after turn `DETACHED` on. A little improvement could be done by [using `break`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18488730/2989289)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand, docker-compose run --user is an option, and the docker-compose.yml supports the user key (http://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#working95dir-entrypoint-user-hostname-domainname-mem95limit-privileged-restart-stdin95open-tty-cpu95shares).

Comment: docker-compose -rm up is not supported as far as I researched. Wonder if there's rm key available in docker-compose.yml. I looked through the document can't see to find it.