# stop container after finishing entrypoint script

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, sh

I plan to start a separate container (via compose) which configures my mongodb replica set. After configuration (via entrypoint sh script) the container is not needed anymore. Whats the best way to kill/stop him from shell?

Comment: Maybe the `--rm` option is what you're searching for, see, e.g., https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

Comment: looks interesting, thanks. but that means i have to start all containers in compose file separatly because there is one which needs --rm option?

Comment: Yeah, I think so...I would run the setup before with the `--rm` option and then start all services like `docker-compose up service_1 service_2 ...` This could also be of interest to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207616/auto-remove-container-with-docker-compose-yml (Auto remove container with docker-compose.yml)

Comment: The container will stop (exit) as soon as your Entrypoint script exit, say when it finishes its execution.  You don't need any special for this.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever is launched first by the entrypoint command will be PID 1 in the Container. When PID 1 exits/stops, the Container will stop.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try!