# How can you automatically run and remove a container in docker compose

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

I'm looking to forwarding my ssh-agent and found this
https://github.com/nardeas/ssh-agent

and the steps are the following

**0. Build**
Navigate to the project directory and launch the following command to build the image:

```
docker build -t docker-ssh-agent:latest -f Dockerfile .
```

**1. Run a long-lived container**

```
docker run -d --name=ssh-agent docker-ssh-agent:latest
```

**2. Add your ssh keys**
Run a temporary container with volume mounted from host that includes your SSH keys. SSH key id_rsa will be added to ssh-agent (you can replace id_rsa with your key name):

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from=ssh-agent -v ~/.ssh:/.ssh -it docker-ssh-agent:latest ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

*The ssh-agent container is now ready to use.*

**3. Add ssh-agent socket to other container:**
*If you're using docker-compose this is how you forward the socket to a container:*

```
volumes_from:
  - ssh-agent
environment:
  - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/.ssh-agent/socket
```

in a compose file, I add step 1 to it like so:

```
services:
  ssh_agent:
    image: nardeas/ssh-agent
```

However I do not what's the equivalent syntax in **compose file** for step 2

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from=ssh-agent -v ~/.ssh:/.ssh -it docker-ssh-agent:latest ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207616/auto-remove-container-with-docker-compose-yml)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below -

```
docker-compose -f my-docker-compose.yml run --rm ssh_agent bash -c "ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

Comment: how to do that inside docker-compose file though

Answer (score -1):

docker-compose.yml file will be

```
services:
  ssh_agent:
  image: docker-ssh-agent:latest
  command: ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa
  volumes_from:
    - ssh-agent
  environment:
    - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/.ssh-agent/socket
  volumes:
    - ~/.ssh:/.ssh
```

then run the docker-compose command as below

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm ssh_agent
```

Comment: Or you could add the line `restart: "no"` to the service definition.

Comment: OP wants to do it within yml without the `--rm` option