# How to copy file to a container in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose and a docker file.

In the docker file, I have COPY instructions where I specify

The problem is, I have a new JAR file in the same folder as my dockerfile but it keeps copying the older jar. I have no idea of where it is getting the older jar. I have made sure to have only one jar.

COPY ./xxxx.jar /home/dev/xxxxd.jar

Comment: can you build the image with no cache

docker-compose build --no-cache

Comment: Exactly, I have found the culprit. the images were not rebuilt but rather taken from a previous build. I don't if we could force the images to be rebuild or delete the images when the containers are deleted

Answer (score 1):

So let's say your `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY ./xxxx.jar /home/dev/xxxxd.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/home/dev/xxxxd.jar"]
```

You have some folder for your project like

```
project/
    Dockerfile
    docker-compose.yml
    xxxx.jar
    old-xxxx.jar
```

You can make your `docker-compose.yml` look like this:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  project:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/dev
```

This line will copy the jar to the image at build time

```
COPY ./xxxx.jar /home/dev/xxxxd.jar
```

This docker-compose volume part is going to run docker container similar to using the following docker run command.

```
docker run -v ./:/home/dev project
```

This will mount your project folder to the `/home/dev` before running.
Which should have your most recent jar which is the same jar as in your project folder.

If you are noticing something unusual you can try what I do when things go wrong.

```
docker-compose up --build
```

and if all else fails:

```
docker-compose stop && docker-compose rm -sfv && docker-compose up
```

Similar issues:

[How do I mount a host directory as a volume in docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905761/how-do-i-mount-a-host-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-compose)

[Auto remove container with docker-compose.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207616/auto-remove-container-with-docker-compose-yml)

Answer (score 0):

Docker might be using the cache layer. That's why the file doesn't change. Try to rebuild the image:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

or, for building and running all together:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

---

Also, for those who want to copy a file from or to a container for a one-off task like testing you can use:

```
docker cp host_source_path container:destination_path
```

or

```
docker cp container:source_path host_destination_path
```